# Relative isotopy between a disk homeomorphism that fixes the boundary and the identity

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've been going through prior exam questions preparing for an exam in an intro to algebraic topology class and I stumbled upon this one:

Let $h: D^2 \rightarrow D^2$ be a homeomorphism such that $h\restriction_{S^1} = \operatorname{Id} _{S^1}$. Prove that there exists a relative homotopy $H:h \simeq \operatorname{Id} _{D^2} ($rel $S^1 )$ such that, for all $t \in [0,1]$, *the map $H(\cdot,t): D^2 \rightarrow D^2$ is a homeomorphism*  (the definition of what an isotopy is).

I'm really stuck on this question and don't know how to approach it. The only thing I can think of is the line homotopy $$H(x,t) = (1-t)h(x) + t \operatorname{Id} _{D^2}(x),$$ but I don't think it satisfies that isotopy condition. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Define $H(x,t)$ to equal $x$ if $x\ge1-t$ and to equal $(1-t)h(x/(1-t))$ for $x<1-t$. Pictorially, this means to have $H(\cdot,t)$ be a shrunk copy of $h$ on the disk of radius $1-t$ and the identity outside that disk.